Is there any wifi microcontroller without blobs in firmware?
Something like ESP8266, ESP-32 but without closed source blobs. I've heard about the pinecone nutcracker challenge(bl602) but haven't found any results. Does anyone know if there is a replacement for blobs on bl602?
